# Unzip to a directory and run commands on the unzipped folder from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following commands in my shell script,

```
sudo mkdir targetfolder
sudo chmod 777 targetfolder
unzip srcfile.zip -d targetfolder
nohup targetfolder/path/executable &
```

when i run the above script it throws an error for the nohup command saying that the path with in target folder does not exist.

If I run these commands one by one from console, they work fine. Basically I think before completing the unzip next command is running.

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `sleep` command inbetween `unzip` and `nohup` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is that you are trying to run the nohup command on a path considering the newly created folder is created from root

So instead of running
`nohup /targetfolder/path/executable &`

try running `nohup targetfolder/path/executable &`

I checked on my system and if there is a valid path `targetfolder/path/executable`, then nohup will not throw an error